# Istanbul code coverage with Mocha and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, istanbul

I have a pretty large AngularJS app that I test browser-less using Mocha and Chai (and JSDom). Works perfectly. However, I am now trying to add code coverage using Istanbul and I keep running into problems with Angular errors.

My test command: `mocha src/**/*.spec.js`
Coverage command: `istanbul cover _mocha src/**/*.spec.js`

The error that I am getting is this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
    at Function.annotate (node_modules/angular/angular.js:3810:24)
    at Function.angular.injector.$$annotate (node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2300:36)
    at Object.invoke (node_modules/angular/angular.js:4514:36)
    at Context.workFn (node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2517:20)
Error: Declaration Location
    at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2488:25)
    at Suite.describe (src/components/filters/emoticonize.spec.js:9:407)
    at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/filters/emoticonize.spec.js:9:183)
    at Object.Module._extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (node_modules/istanbul/lib/hook.js:107:24)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (node_modules/istanbul/lib/hook.js:109:37)
    at runFn (node_modules/istanbul/lib/command/common/run-with-cover.js:122:16)
    at node_modules/istanbul/lib/command/common/run-with-cover.js:251:17
    at node_modules/istanbul/lib/util/file-matcher.js:68:16
    at node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at node_modules/async/lib/async.js:361:13
    at node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at done (node_modules/async/lib/async.js:246:17)
    at node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
    at node_modules/async/lib/async.js:358:17
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:117:15)
```

This is where the error happens: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.x/src/auto/injector.js#L101. I've logged `fnText` there, and when running the tests using Istanbul, that value is

```
_emoticonizeFilter_=>{__cov_OCFuCYwLZAl7nm5crSo1eg.s['7']++;emoticonizeFilter=_emoticonizeFilter_;}
```

My test:

```
require('../../../test-helper');
const expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('filter', () => {
  let emoticonizeFilter;

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('components.filters'));
  beforeEach(inject((_emoticonizeFilter_) => {
    emoticonizeFilter = _emoticonizeFilter_;
  }));

  describe('emoticonize', () => {
    it('should replace a smiley :) with emoji ', () => {
      expect(emoticonizeFilter('Hello :)', true)).to.equal('Hello ');
    });

    it('should not replace smileys when given a falsy parameter', () => {
      expect(emoticonizeFilter('Hello :)', false)).to.equal('Hello :)');
    });
  });
});
```

So it's breaking in that `beforeEach` where I inject `_emoticonizeFilter_`. Istanbul is adding stuff that Angular doesn't know how to handle in its annotate function.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by upgrading from Angular 1.4.x to 1.5.x.